# any reason behind writing looks are?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I know that the noun *looks* usually takes plural form, eg:

*Her looks are deceptive.*

But since *looks* is an uncountable noun, why does it take a plural verb? Shouldn't it be treated like the other uncountable nouns - love, happiness, news or beauty etc. and be treated as singular? Specially when we use beauty in a similar context, we say -

*Her beauty is what makes her special.*

but the moment we switch to looks, we say -

*Her looks are what make her special.*

Can anyone explain why this is so.

Comment: I don't know why you say ***looks** is an uncountable noun* - it's not (unlike, say, ***hair***, which can be). In your context, ***looks*** is an ordinary plural, no different to *His ideas are what I like about him*  (if he has several ideas you find attractive), as compared to *His **idea is** what I like about him* (there's *one idea of his in particular* that interests you).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's not hard to figure out why the OP thinks this might be an uncountable noun. When talking about "her looks," it's not like there are multiple looks we are talking about, as in: _I like her two looks – her left look and her right look_.

Comment: @J.R.: Are there ***any*** "uncountable nouns" formed by appending "pluralising" ***s*** to a singular noun form? It sounds unlikely to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't either, but I know why *I'd* call it an uncountable noun: because you can't count it!  In this meaning, it makes no sense to talk of *one look, two looks, three looks*, although these phrases are of course fine if you understand them with a different sort of meaning.  Compare *international waters*, which is also plural and uncountable, although *water* can be singular or count in other meanings (*two waters, please*).  Likewise, *some oats* but not *\*an oat* or *\*two oats*.

Comment: @snailboat: I'm not big on precise grammatical terminology, but are you sure *[international] **waters*** is an uncountable noun?

Comment: Insofar as you can't count them: *\*an international water, \*two international waters, \*three international waters*.  If you disagree and judge these examples acceptable, I'd be surprised, but in that case we could go with the *\*an oat, \*two oats* example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I can give a definitive answer to your excellent question. However, I can point out that there are a few nouns in English which look and sound plural even when they are used as a singular word. When this happens, we sometimes treat the word as though it were plural – perhaps because it just sounds more natural to our ear.

Some examples would include:

> These **scissors are** dull.
>
> There is a hole in **these pants**! I can't wear **them**.
>
> These **tweezers are** sharp! Be careful with them.

Similarly, some English nouns are plural, but they appear singular and therefore are treated as singular words – much to the consternation of some purists:

> The **data has been** corrupted.

Note: some might argue that *data* is plural and therefore should be treated as a plural word, but there is an interesting blog post about that [here](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2010/jul/16/data-plural-singular). It says (among other things):

> It's like *agenda*, a Latin plural that is now almost universally used as a singular. Technically the singular is *datum/agendum*, but we feel it sounds increasingly hyper-correct, old-fashioned and pompous to say "the data are".

An [EnglishPlus grammar blog post](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000039.htm) entitled *Tricky Plurals* points out that branches of knowledge ending with -s (such as *physics* and *ethics*) are treated as singulars, as are diseases (such as *measles* and *mumps*), while words that end with -s and represent a pair (such as *pliers* or *eyeglasses*) are treated as plurals.

I find the word you ask about – *looks* – rather unique. It's no disease, it's not a branch of knowledge, and it doesn't represent a pair. [Wiktionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/looks) defines *looks* with two noun definition:

> `n.` Plural form of look.
>   `n.` One's appearance or attractiveness.

In that second usage, you are correct, we typically treat it as a plural noun, even though it's pretty much synonymous with *beauty*:

> Her looks **are** stunning. Her beauty **is** stunning.

although we can use *look* in the singular, too:

> She has an alluring look.

Answer (score 1):

"Looks" is a countable noun, which is usually used in the plural, even when the meaning is apparently singular.

A noun used as uncountable is never plural, even when it seems to refer to many things: "This is rice" not *"These are rices". Some nouns are countable but usually plural: trousers, loggerheads, thanks and so on. All are countable and plural, but have no common singular form.

Since "looks" is plural, the verb is "are" for agreement. (third person plural)

There is no special reason for this. English could have evolved differently. But the modern idiom is to use the plural here.  Unlike "trousers" the singular "look" is also quite common.

> He gave her a long look.
>
> The look of 2019 is short sharply cut miniskirts in bold colours.